# Web Wireframe App

Tags: web-design

I am looking for a Web wire frame app that can help me create the mock-up for a website. I am looking for one that is compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 and can be installed if possible with a simple DEB package. Something like gomockingbird or similar sites but instead of a website, an app in Ubuntu. Big plus if it's free in my current case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [other Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=pencil) , [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) is the way to go. It's free, works with 14.04, and it has a DEB package.

[image]

Comment: WOW!, this app is really cool. A couple of things though. Let us say somebody mistakenly installs the "pencil" app found in the Software Center because that someone saw the image here I thought that this app was in the Software Center, he/she would be installing the wrong app. The correct app is in the link provided. It gets worse for that someone if he/she tries to install the correct app after installing the "Pencil" app from the Software Center, they both use a pencil bin file and would conflict over at /bin. That someone would suffer until uninstalling the Software Center "pencil" app.

Comment: Software center doesn't have this app listed see [this](https://copy.com/kAi3eaaPqEXc), it had an app called [Pencil](https://copy.com/Q6TWTN6vsgbN), but it a totally different app.